# Plotting data against overlapping time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 24 hours worth of data collected with a different starting time
I would like to plot both of them on the same plot but because the times do overlap, excel makes the plot jump back to the start? Sorry, I'm not sure how to  explain it but I've attached my data + the screwed up plot. I want the data to start at 2pm and end at 2:12pm the next day without the lines jumping around. How would I go about doing so?

Thanks in advance :)

[Pastebin with data](https://pastebin.com/ATNay9HZ)
[Google drive with excel sheet + plot](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VWnENuYSlnB16-BbB8GEOLeEbnmBB_Zf?usp=sharing)

Comment: Better Copy & Paste sample data instead of attaching download link !!

Comment: Is this about Google Drive or Excel?

Comment: How would Excel know that your hours (time) span 2 days?

Comment: @RajeshS I reuploaded the data on pastebin. I'm not sure if it'll be workable in that format :)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I'm not quite sure..i'm a bit of a excel noob. Is there a way to append a date to time for excel to know?

Comment: If you change the data in the first two cells to this format: `2019-10-17  14:00:00` and `2019-10-17  14:01:00` and fill down. Then change the formatting back to `t:mm:ss AM/PM` to hide the date.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Thanks so much! I also changed the bounds using the 'general' form of the starting data and time as the minimum and the 'general' form of the end date and time as the maximum. That plotted the data in in time rather than days if that'll help anyone with a similar problem in the future :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sine Excel has no way to know that *14:00:00* and *14:00:00* are different dates, you get this problem.
You would have to manually add the date to the data, which isn't as hard as it sounds.

So the first cell contains the data `14:00:00`, so you change that to `2019-10-17 14:00:00` or whatever date you like. The cell will probably change to ######### due to the new data not fitting the cell, but don't worry about that.
Then do the same thing on the next row: `14:01:00` to `2019-10-17 14:01:00`, to let excel know that the interval is 1 minute.
With **both** cells selected (`A2:A3`), hold shift and doubleclick the lower right corner of `A3` to autofill the rest of the values.

Then you select the `A`column, format cells, and pick appropriate format, like `t:mm:ss AM/P` or `t:mm AM/P`

Then you probably have to go into the time axel of the plot and reset min and max values.

Result should be something like this: [image]